# Div's not moving with others

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to make it so these divs all move accordingly. So if one row object is shorter than the other, the next row object will pull up twoards it.

This is my problem:

[image]

Please help. My div is set to `display: inline-block;`

http://prntscr.com/4g99di
http://prntscr.com/4g99g3

Comment: Please add your HTML and CSS code, only a screenshot doesn't help.

Comment: Show your honest attempts

Comment: Maybe reading this will push you in the right direction: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout

Comment: @Sebsemillia No thats not what i'm looking for :(. Thanks though. I'm looking for how to make it so the vote will go up to the youtube div. like the donate and news.

Comment: If your goal is something like [Google Keep](http://tinyurl.com/ndotgt4) then I'm affraid you are going to have to calculate the position of the divs. Google Keep uses absolutely positioned divs in combination with the `-webkit-transform: translate(px, px);`. Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Can you generate the HTML as columns rather than rows?
Instead of:

```
row
  YouTube
  News
  Recent Posts
/row
row
  Vote
  Donate
/row
```

Maybe do:

```
row
  col
    YouTube
    Vote
  /col
  col
    News
    Donate
  /col
  col
    Recent Posts
  /col
/row
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with masonry plugin. Here is my example:

HTML:

```
<script src="http://masonry.desandro.com/js/masonry-docs.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<div class="item">
    <h2>DIV 1</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
</div>
<div class="item">
    <h2>DIV 2</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat.
</div>
<div class="item">
    <h2>DIV 3</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
</div>
<div class="item">
    <h2>DIV 4</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat.
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  columnWidth: 200,
  itemSelector: '.item'
});
```

CSS:

```
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
```

jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/1ba5t64b/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS3 column to solve this problem:

Apply this class in content

```
  -webkit-column-width: 300px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-width: 300px; /* Firefox */
  column-width: 300px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-gap: 20px; /* Firefox */
  column-gap: 20px;
```

you can see an example in http://codepen.io/oriolet/pen/avztJ/